# ? character in SP for single character wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a TSQL stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchEntityDataNew]
@SearchText varchar(100) = '*'  
AS
BEGIN    

   IF CHARINDEX('*', @SearchText) = 0
      SET @SearchText = '%' + @SearchText + '%' 
   ELSE
      SET @SearchText = REPLACE(@SearchText, '*', '%')

  SELECT 'Entity' as pagetype,EntityID,EntityData,EntityDataID 
    FROM EntityData 
    WHERE  EntityData LIKE @SearchText
  union all
  SELECT 'Property' as pagetype,PropertyID,PropertyValue,EntityDataID  
    FROM EntityDataProperty 
    WHERE  PropertyValue LIKE @SearchText
END
```

I want to allow `?` in it which will be equal to the `_` operator.

How can I allow `?` so that if user types t_ then 'to' is returned. If user types _t then 'It' is returned?

Comment: If it's just one character, you can use the wildcard (match one character) operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174424.aspx

Comment: I need to add one character wild card in above stored procedure so that if user types t? then 'to' is returned if user types 't%' then to and too both are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already replace `*` with `%`, so just replace `?` with `_` in your `@SearchText` variable also.

Comment: Underscore is the way to go here, +1. For reference, here is the documentation on LIKE : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx